# Can't drag 'imrect' object for high resolution images

Tags: matlab, user-interface, image-processing

I'm making a GUI (with GUIDE) in which there is an axis used to display image sequences. In order to let the user select a region of interest in the sequence I'm using 'imrect'. The problem is the following: everything goes fine when images are smaller than 512x512 pixels (approximately), however for larger images (I tried 600x600 and 1024x1024) the rectangle does appear, I can change its size but I can't drag it around. I though it had to be with axis units so I changed the property from 'pixels' to 'normalized' and use normalized coordinates, but it does not work.

Here is my code to create the rectangle and restrain its movement to the axis limits:

```
hROI = imrect(hVideo,[Width/4 Height/4 Width/2 Height/2]; % Arbitrary size and position of the rectangle, centered on the image.

fcn = makeConstrainToRectFcn('imrect',get(gca,'XLim'),get(gca,'YLim'));
setPositionConstraintFcn(hROI,fcn);
```

When I perform the same operation on those large images outside the GUI it works. Any hint is welcome!
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to the problem, in case it can help someone:

In the call to imshow just before calling imrect, we need to specify the axis limits as the "XData" and "YData" parameters.

Example:

```
imshow(Movie{Frame},'parent',handles.axes1_Video,'XData',get(gca,'XLim'),'YData',get(gca,'YLim'))
```

It works for images up to 1024x1024.